# Using Google Cloud Speech and Unity, can't authenticate speech requests, but only on certain computers

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-speech

This is the error Unity is spitting out in the logs, over and over:

```
Status(StatusCode=Unauthenticated, Detail="Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.")
```

More context is:

I use cloud speech for work and it's working fine everywhere except for one customer's computer. The app is built with Unity and uses the gRPC plugin to do the streaming variant of cloud speech. The customer is in another country but my first guess is that wouldn't matter, as we have other customers in the same country that don't have this issue.

I tried looking through the documentation Google provides for error codes and this one isn't in there. I looked through the troubleshooting section and saw something about authentication. I supply the credentials at runtime from a JSON file stored in the app. The code when using the credentials looks something like this:

```
googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(Utils.DecodeBase64(encodedCredentials));       
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());
var speech = SpeechClient.Create(channel);
```

I'm trying to gather more information here so we can narrow down our troubleshooting to help the customer get the app running. Like does this point towards a specific router/firewall setting kind of thing, etc?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue for this? I am wondering how to get the credentials dynamically too

Comment: No, sorry. I never did.